# android studioのundo回数設定

Tags: android, android-studio

android studioのundo回数が無制限ではないようで
元に戻そうとしても途中までしか戻らない事が多々有ります。

回数を無制限にしたいのですが、設定を変更するする方法をご存知ないでしょうか
（File→Settingsで探したのですが見つけられませんでした）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

undoは試してないので、うまくいくか分かりませんが。

1. `Android Studio`の`Help`メニューの`Find Action...`を選択
2. 出てきたポップアップの`Include non-menu actions`にチェックを入れ、検索エディットに`registry`を入力
3. `Registry`を選択すると`Registry`ダイアログが出てくる。
4. `undo.documentUndoLimit`と`undo.globalUndoLimit`がそれっぽい設定な気がします。

追記
試してみたのですが、`undo.documentUndoLimit`が`Undo`可能な回数となるようです。
ただし、Undo無制限の方法は見つかりませんでした（`0`や`-1`、未設定値ではダメでした）
この値は`int`で指定するようなので、2147483647がUndo可能な最大値となるようです。

Comment: 早速2147483647に変更しました。（これをデフォルトにすれば良いのに）
おかげ様で便利になりました、ありがとうございます。

PHPStormですが、http://uzulla.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/02/26/124646こちらに画像付きで説明しているサイトがありましたので、リンクしておきます。